# Move last column title name and put to be on first column on all rows

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Want to get the last column in the title in that example is "db5b", and to place in to the first column on every next row.

Output:

```
                                  Filesystem utilization for db5b

/dev/hd4           3.00      2.87    5%     5728     1% /
/dev/hd2           7.00      2.79   61%    61845     9% /usr
/dev/hd9var        7.00      5.88   17%      861     1% /var
/dev/hd3           3.00      2.98    1%      205     1% /tmp
```

Expected result:

```
db5b 5% /
db5b 61% /usr
db5b 17% /var
db5b 1% /tmp
```

I use that but not able to figure out how to place db5b to be on the first column:

```
awk '{print $3, $7}'
```

I guess if want to finish the result with awk to use NF but not sure how to finish the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one-liner gives what you wanted:

```
awk 'NR==1{t=$NF;next}$0{print t,$4,$NF}' file
```

**EDIT**

for different titles:

```
awk 'NF==4{t=$NF;next}$0{print t,$4,$NF}' file
```

Comment: when I have multiple output with different title names it's copy only the first one title for all result

Comment: @KalinBorisov please test the one-liner in my **EDIT**

Answer (score 2):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {a=$NF} NR>1 && $0 {print a,$4,$7}' file
db5b 5% /
db5b 61% /usr
db5b 17% /var
db5b 1% /tmp
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==1 {a=$NF}` on first line, save the last field into var `a`.
- `NR>1 && $0 {print a,$4,$7}` on lines after the first with some data, print the value plus 4th and 7th fields.

---

And for an input like [Vijay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20215109/1983854):

```
$ awk '/Filesystem/ {a=$NF} /^\// {print a,$4,$7}' file
db5b 5% /
db5b 61% /usr
db5b 17% /var
db5b 1% /tmp
db6b 5% /
db6b 61% /usr
db6b 17% /var
db6b 1% /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$4!~/%/ && NF>0{a=$NF;next}{print a,$4,$7}' your_file
```

Test:

```
> cat temp
                                  Filesystem utilization for db5b
/dev/hd4           3.00      2.87    5%     5728     1% /
/dev/hd2           7.00      2.79   61%    61845     9% /usr
/dev/hd9var        7.00      5.88   17%      861     1% /var
/dev/hd3           3.00      2.98    1%      205     1% /tmp
                                  Filesystem utilization for db6b
/dev/hd4           3.00      2.87    5%     5728     1% /
/dev/hd2           7.00      2.79   61%    61845     9% /usr
/dev/hd9var        7.00      5.88   17%      861     1% /var
/dev/hd3           3.00      2.98    1%      205     1% /tmp
> awk '$4!~/%/ && NF>0{a=$NF;next}{print a,$4,$7}' temp
db5b 5% /
db5b 61% /usr
db5b 17% /var
db5b 1% /tmp
db6b 5% /
db6b 61% /usr
db6b 17% /var
db6b 1% /tmp
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something non-awk:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

while read -r
do
output=$(echo "${REPLY}" | tr -s ' ')
drive=$(echo "${output}" | cut -f7)
percent=$(echo "${output}" | cut -f4)

echo -e "db5b\t${percent}\t${drive}"
done < fs_utilisation
```

The -e switch to echo may be bash-only, and thus non-portable.  I apologise if so; you will have to check.  The reason why I used the -e switch is because it will interpret \t to give you tabs between your fields.